# How to copy existing files into a zip folder in Julia

Tags: zip, julia, filesystems

I am trying to copy some existing files (using full file paths) into a zip folder that I have created using the Julia Language.

So far I have tried both ZipFile.jl and InfoZIP and neither package has been able to add existing files to the zip folder, just create new one to write into.  If anyone has any tips for how to generate a new zip folder and fill it with pre-existing files I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can read each file and write it into the archive :

```
w = ZipFile.Writer("archive.zip")
for filepath in filelist
    f = open(filepath, "r")
    content = read(f, String)
    close(f)
    zf = ZipFile.addfile(w, basename(filepath));
    write(zf, content)
end
close(w)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this functionality, too. The [ZipArchives.jl](https://docs.juliahub.com/General/ZipArchives/stable/autodocs/) package now seems to provide it.

As a relative newcomer, I found the docs a little tricky to decode, but it was worth persevering!

Here is a very simple mwe:

```
using ZipArchives

zipfile = "test.zip"
newfile = "test1.csv"
appfile = "test2.docx"

# Read first file and write to zip.
f = open(newfile, "r")
    content = read(f, String)
close(f)    
ZipWriter(zipfile) do w
    zip_newfile(w, newfile; compress=true )
    write(w, content)
end
# end of do block closes the zip.

# Now read the next file to append
f = open(appfile, "r")
content = read(f, String)
close(f)

# In this do block, files are appended to the existing zip file.
zip_append_archive(zipfile) do w
    zip_newfile(w, appfile; compress=true)
    write(w, content)
end
```